# Incorrect limit in complex quantity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, complex

I have the following quantity

$$ f = \frac{\exp(\sqrt{-k^2-i\epsilon}d)}{\sqrt{-k^2-i\epsilon}} $$

and form the limit as $\epsilon\to0$. Mathematica does not produce the correct result.

Code:

```
f = -(E^(Sqrt[-k^2 - I ϵ] d)/Sqrt[-k^2 - I ϵ]);

g1 = Limit[f, ϵ -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", 
   Assumptions -> Element[{k}, Reals] && ϵ >= 0];
g2 = Limit[f, ϵ -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", 
   Assumptions -> Element[{k}, Reals] && ϵ >= 0 && k > 0];
```

The second one gives the correct result for positive $k$, the first one yields the complex conjugate. Of course this is related to various branch cut things, but I am very surprised that the assumption $k>0$ would yield any difference, since only $k^2$ appears in the equation.

By "correct result" I mean the limit as $\epsilon\to0^+$. I can take e.g. $\epsilon=10^{-10}$ and get a result that agrees with the $g_2$ up to errors of $\mathcal O(10^{-10})$, but not with $g_1$.

Comment: Remove the assumptions `\[Epsilon] >= 0` (because "Limit::alimv: Warning: Assumptions that involve the limit variable are ignored.") The results `g1 , g2` are both correct.

Comment: the math formula and the MMA code are different ($k$ vs $k^2$). Also, what is the expected output? what is the "correct result" you are after? Is the limit understood in the sense of distributions? MMA cannot handle that, so don't expect it to.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is supposed to be $k^2$ everywhere. I have made more precise what I mean by "correct" result.

Comment: Note that `Direction->"FromAbove"` is in contradiction with `\[Epsilon\>0`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Maybe that's the origin of my confusion? I was under the impression that "FromAbove" would mean that epsilon is non-negative? In which case epsilon>=0 is true.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Thanks a lot for your comment, I must have overlooked it. I've tried your suggestion, and $g_1$ doesn't change, $g_2$ becomes Indeterminate, but neither agrees with taking $f$ with very small (positive) values of $\epsilon$. Also (i) how can the limit exist for real $k$, but not for positive $k$? This makes no sense.

Comment: Oh boy. You are right, it is equivalent to `Direction->-1`. I thought it was equivalent to `Direction->-I`. So it is my confusion. Not sure what else if going on other than the assumption `k>0` rules out the isolated case of `k==0`.

Comment: This is not complex limit, what you did. By default it is Real limit. Also, FromAbove alredy gives the needed Assumptions, those are prohibited on the limit variable. So, this will give you what you need,
g1 = Limit[f, \\[Epsilon] -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove" ]
g2 = Limit[f, \\[Epsilon] -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove", 
   Assumptions -> Element[{k}, Reals] && k > 0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely a bug, apparently `Limit` is playing fast and loose with exponentials of logs.  I will file a bug.  But the correct answer is to take the `g1` and replace `Abs[k]` with `-Abs[k]`.

```
FullSimplify[(g1 /. Abs[k] -> -Abs[k]) == g2, k > 0]
(*True*)
```

And if you defined `g3` for `k<0`, you also find:

```
FullSimplify[(g1 /. Abs[k] -> -Abs[k]) == g3, k < 0]
(*True*)
```

BTW, you don't need the assumption `k\[Element]Reals` in `g2` and `g3`.  If you put an assumption with an inequality, both sides are assumed to be real.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with `Conjugate ...`  takes into acount, that k can be zero.

Let me give you an overview, that all solutions are true.

```
f = -(E^(Sqrt[-k^2 - I \[Epsilon]] d)/Sqrt[-k^2 - I \[Epsilon]]);

{{" ", " ", "k>0", "k<0"}, {"Direction\[Rule]1,k\[Element]Reals", 
g1 = Limit[f, \[Epsilon] -> 0, Direction -> 1, 
 Assumptions -> Element[{k}, Reals]], Simplify[g1, k > 0], 
Simplify[g1, k < 0]}, {"Direction\[Rule]-1,k\[Element]Reals", 
g2 = Limit[f, \[Epsilon] -> 0, Direction -> -1, 
 Assumptions -> Element[{k}, Reals]], Simplify[g2, k > 0], 
Simplify[g2, k < 0]}, {"Direction\[Rule]1,k\[Element]Reals,k!=0", 
g3 = Limit[f, \[Epsilon] -> 0, Direction -> 1, 
 Assumptions -> Element[{k}, Reals] && k != 0], 
Simplify[g3, k > 0], 
Simplify[g3, k < 0]}, {"Direction\[Rule]-1,k\[Element]Reals,k!=0", 
g4 = Limit[f, \[Epsilon] -> 0, Direction -> -1, 
 Assumptions -> Element[{k}, Reals] && k != 0], 
Simplify[g4, k > 0], Simplify[g4, k < 0]}, {"Direction\[Rule]1", " ",
 g5 = Limit[f, \[Epsilon] -> 0, Direction -> 1, 
 Assumptions -> k > 0], 
 g6 = Limit[f, \[Epsilon] -> 0, Direction -> 1, 
 Assumptions -> k < 0]}, {"Direction\[Rule]-1", " ", 
 g7 = Limit[f, \[Epsilon] -> 0, Direction -> -1, 
 Assumptions -> k > 0], 
 g8 = Limit[f, \[Epsilon] -> 0, Direction -> -1, 
 Assumptions -> k < 0]}} // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You deal with a complex-valued function so the `Direction->Complexes` option does the job:

```
Limit[Exp[Sqrt[-k^2 - I*\[Epsilon]]*d]/Sqrt[-k^2 - I*\[Epsilon]], 
\[Epsilon] -> 0, Direction -> Complexes,GenerateConditions->True]
(* ConditionalExpression[E^(d Sqrt[-k^2])/Sqrt[-k^2], k != 0 && Im[k^2] != 0]*)
```

Addition. The same result is produced by

```
Limit[Exp[Sqrt[-k^2 - I*\[Epsilon]]*d]/Sqrt[-k^2 - I*\[Epsilon]], \[Epsilon] -> 0,GenerateConditions->True]
```

Comment: If the limit exists, then so do the directional limits  and the results are equal.

Comment: `Direction->Complexes` is not relevant to this problem.   Limit doesn't show the conditions for by default, but if you add `GenerateConditions->True`, you'll see that this result is only valid for non-real and non-pure-imaginary k.

Comment: @Itai Seggev: Thank you for your valuable comment. Fixed.

Comment: @Itai Seggev: Maple confirms E^(d Sqrt[-k^2])/Sqrt[-k^2] without any conditions. Maple says there is no branch cut at the origin if $\epsilon=\frac 1 {100}$. See https://www.dropbox.com/s/zrz5idxw2xfbg7r/limit.pdf?dl=0 .

Comment: There is a branch cut for $k$ real.  You can see this by comparing, for example `With[{f = f /. k -> 1 /. d -> 1}, ComplexPlot3D[f, {\[Epsilon], 1}]]` and `With[{f = f /. k -> 1+1 /. d -> 1}, ComplexPlot3D[f, {\[Epsilon], 1}]]`.  Also `{f, -(E^(d Sqrt[-k^2])/Sqrt[-k^2])} /. d -> 1. /.  k -> 1  /. \[Epsilon] -> 10.^-10` shows that the generic result is wrong for real $k$.